# Designing test system that includes a test client, a test server and a system under test

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, test-automation-framework

I'm trying to design a test system  to test an embedded realtime software. What is the best option for creating a test system like below? 
Is it possible to use TTCN-3 to control hardware components like UART or Digital I/O Card to stimulate SUT?

```
 _________________________
|   Test Operator Client  |  <- Test Script  [Operator]
 -------------------------   
   | Test Behavior    ^
   v                  | Test Result 
 ________________________
|  Test Execution Server |
 ------------------------   
    | Stimulation (Send UART Message, Set Digital Output etc...) 
    |              ^
    |              | Observe SUT Response ( timestamp, digital/analog IO etc...)
    v              |  
 ___________________________________
|   System Under Test (Real Time)   | 
 -----------------------------------
```

Comment: your question is too wide, try to narrow it down for a specific area.